# A gust of wind made me lose a couple of my hats

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, fun, winter-bash-2020

Till a couple of hours back I was having a collection of 20 odd colorful hats. All of a sudden now it seems a gust of wind made me lose a couple of my hats.

I am aware about [Yaakov Ellis's Hat Maintenance Note](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56450361#56450361):

> I fixed a bug in the secret definition of Vexillologist, removed the hat from all users (since a good number who earned it should not have, based on a bug in the sql) and reawarded to all users who should earn it. Anyone who is earning it now will get a new WB inbox notification. So if you are trying to figure out the hat, just look at hats awarded from [now - 5 minutes] and on.

Were there more similar incidences?

> PS: I've managed to hide my Vexillologist hats within my cupboard up till now

Comment: Yes, there was a second incident; turns out the secret definition was wrong again.

Comment: That gust of wind is a popular theme: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403778

Comment: You can probably call it *inspired by* and get away with it ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here's an explanation for the gust of wind](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56467555):

> **mea culpa #3** - really hope this is the last time, but I just cleared all hat owners for balalaika and disciple. Both are secret, and both had something messed up with their triggers (and if I didn't clear them, then would be very hard to figure out what they are for). If you earned [them], they will be awarded to you again shortly.