# Milliner awarded before the trigger was met!

Tags: bug, status-declined, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020, winterbash-leaderboard

The leaderboard for Literature shows 10 hats for me, but Milliner is in the list which is supposed to be available after a total of 11 hats are earned.

[image]

How is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible that you had Balalaika and Disciple which put you at 11 hats, then the hats were removed as part of the [fix for incorrectly awarded hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358226/a-gust-of-wind-made-me-lose-a-couple-of-my-hats).

Comment: This is it. If it makes you feel better, I can remove your Milliner hat as well...

Comment: @YaakovEllis LOL. You will eventually take all of them away.

Comment: It's also possible that people received the "Propel thyself" hat incorrectly this way (I did).